# Calculate point that is equally distant from three specific points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, geometry, distance

I have this simple data set:

```
Class1 = [1 0; 0.5 1; 0.5 1.5];
```

How do I go about finding the point on the 2d space that is of equal Euclidean distance from all three points of the data set?

[image]

The point highlighted in orange should roughly be where the calculated point is.

Comment: Your last question confuses me. Do you want to determine the one of the 3 points which is closest to an arbitrary point you choose? Or something else altogether? If the former, then [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) in the statistics toolbox would be of use. If you look at "related" questions on the right -->, you'll see several encouraging posts with answers.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I wanted to calculate a knn point, given the three points.  I placed that point in the diagram (in orange) to show possibly where the calculated point should be.  Is there a way to go about calculating the orange point that satisfies the knn algorithm?

Comment: Yeah, one of us is missing the point. A 'knn point' is *one of your input points*, that is closest to "something". What do you need a closest neighbour of? OR, if that's not what you want, you need to be more clear. Your orange point is not in your point set, so it can't be a nearest neighbour. Neighbours are all in your set. So what defined that orange point? A point in 2d space which is equally far from your 3 points? That doesn't have anything to do with a concept of a nearest neighbour!

Comment: I am trying to generate a knn based boundary given the above class and another class of data.  I was thinking of a way to generate one point from the given data set and then another point from the second data set and then creating a line joining the two points.  Once I have that line, I would then find the perpendicular line that should give me the knn boundary.  From your comments, I cannot do this based on the knn algorithm?

Comment: OK, then your requirements are still unclear to me. If you need the point that is equally far from your 3 points, I added an answer. If that's *not* what you need, please let me know, and I'll delete it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, thanks for your time and comments, I do need a point that is equally far from the 3 points.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited your question in an attempt to make it clearer, I also retagged it. Please feel free to revert any of it if you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a point with equal distances from the three points, you can create the corresponding symbolic equations and solve them. Let's separate the points to `P1 = [1 0]`, `P2 = [0.5 1]` and `P3 = [0.5 1.5]`.

```
syms x y
% [x, y] has equal distance from P1 and P2:
eqn1 = (P1(1)-x).^2 + (P1(2)-y).^2 == (P2(1)-x).^2 + (P2(2)-y).^2;
% [x, y] has equal distance from P1 and P3:
eqn2 = (P1(1)-x).^2 + (P1(2)-y).^2 == (P3(1)-x).^2 + (P3(2)-y).^2;
[a, b] = solve([eqn1, eqn2], [x, y])

% a =
% 
% 9/4
% 
% 
% b =
% 
% 5/4
```

Generally, working with symbolic variables and equations is not a reasonable choice if you are dealing  with a large amount of data. Otherwise, it is convenient for writing math in a compact and simple way.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.  What about P2 - P3? Does that contribute?

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe I do not get your question, but `P1`, `P2` and `P3` are all considered in `eqn1` and `eqn2`.

Comment: Yes, true, but if we used this equation instead:  `% [x, y] has equal distance from P2 and P3:
eqn2 = (P2(1)-x).^2 + (P2(2)-y).^2 == (P3(1)-x).^2 + (P3(2)-y).^2;`  would this now change the solution that we would get?

Comment: `a == b && a == c` implies `b == c`. That equation does not add any information. Could we replace any of equations with your suggestion? Yes! You can choose any 2 out of the 3.

Comment: Sincerest THANKS for all your time and help!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to find the point which is equally far from all 3 points (which I concluded from your hints in comments), you're essentially looking for the center of the circle that contains all three points. Note that there is either 1 or 0 such circle, depending on whether your three points are collinear (i.e. whether they are aligned on a line).

Your simplest choice is looking at two radii of the circle, and looking at their intersection. If you imagine for a moment that you know the circle, you can easily see that any two of your points define secants of your circle, so the perpendicular bisector of these secants will intersect in the center of the circle. If the points are aligned on a line, all these bisectors will be parallel, i.e. they won't have an intersection (which makes sense: a line is a circle with infinite radius).

So you need to look at the equations of the perpendicular bisectors of your points, `p1 = [x1,y1]`, `p2 = [x2,y2]` and `p3 = [x3,y3]`. The first perpendicular bisector defined by the first two points goes through `q1 = (p1+p2)/2`, and is perpendicular to `n1 = p1-p2`, so its direction vector is `v1 = [y1-y2,x2-x1]`. Now you need to do the same for another pair of points:

```
q2 = (p1+p3)/2;
v2 = [y1-y3,x3-x1];
```

Then the points of your two perpendicular bisectors are defined by

```
q1 + t1*v1
q2 + t2*v2
```

with `t1`, `t2` real parameters, respectively. What you need to do is solve for `t1` and `t2` such that the two lines intersect in `O = [ox,oy]`:

```
q1 + t1*v1 = q2 + t2*v2
t1*v1 - t2*v2 = q2 - q1
```

This latter is a 2d vector equation: two inhomogeneous linear equations for the two parameters `t1` and `t2`. If you solve it in the usual way, either component of the solution `[tsol1; tsol2]` will give you the coordinates of the origin:

```
O = q1 + tsol1*v1 == q2 + tsol2*v2
```

The linear equation will not have a solution exactly when the two bisectors are parallel and don't go through the same point (i.e. your three points are aligned along a line). The linear equation will be trivial and have infinitely many solutions exactly when the two bisectors coincide (i.e. if two of your points coincide).

In non-degenerate cases the equations should have a unique solution, from which you can derive the center of the circle.